# one handler for many instance

Tags: c#, event-handling

I have 2 instances from one class.

```
Rectangle first = new Rectangle();
OnErrorHandler handler = new OnErrorHandler(Rectangle_OnError);
first.OnError += handler;
second.OnError += handler;

first.Width = 10;
first.Height = -5;

second.Width = -4;
second.Height = 2;

first.OnError -= handler;
first.Width = -1;
Rectangle second = new Rectangle();
```

and I want to know which instance creates event?

```
namespace EventSample
{
    public delegate void OnErrorHandler(string message);    
}

public class Rectangle
{
    public event OnErrorHandler OnError;

    private int _Width;
    private int _Height;

    public int Width
    {
        get
        {
            return _Width;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value < 0)
            {
                if (OnError != null)
                    OnError("Width can not be less than zero!");

                return;
            }

            _Width = value;
        }
    }
```

thanks for your help.

Comment: Why aren't you using exceptions?

Answer (score 2):

As ChaosPandion said above, you should use exceptions to inform about error conditions.

Assuming that you still want to use events, you should use the proper convention for event handlers in C#.  This involves using the predefined `EventHandler<TEventArgs>` delegate rather than creating your own delegate.  The signature is this:

```
public delegate void EventHandler<TEventArgs>(object sender, TEventArgs e);
```

The important part in this case is the `sender`, which by convention is the instance which raised the event.  The typical way to raise the event is like this:

```
EventHandler<MyEventArgs> myEvent = this.MyEvent;
if (myEvent != null)
{
    // pass 'this' as sender to tell who is raising the event
    myEvent(this, new MyEventArgs(/* ... */));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using exceptions for this (as Chaos mentions).

```
if (value < 0)
{
  throw new ArgumentException("Width can not be less than zero!");
}
```

[see MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception.aspx#Y2166)

Comment: i want to know whitch instance fire event?